# Pass multiple php variables in onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

```
$ui->button()->value('Save')
             ->uiType('primary')
             ->extras("onclick = helper_reschedule_in_reschedule('".$row->company_id."')")
             ->id("btn_reschedule")
             ->name('submit')
             ->show();
```

This is part of code from a View file of codeigniter. I need to pass three more variables ($row->ppt, $row->test, $row->interview) in Onclick function above.
Function 'helper_reschedule_in_reschedule' from .js file is as below-

```
function helper_reschedule_in_reschedule(company_id){
    var date_from = $("#date_reschedulefrom_"+company_id).val();
    var date_to = $("#date_rescheduleto_"+company_id).val();
    reschedule_in_reschedule(company_id,$date_from,$date_to);   }
```

I tried methods like-

```
->extras("onclick = helper_reschedule_in_reschedule('".$row->company_id.",".$row->ppt.",".$row->test.",".$row->interview."')")
```

but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method parameters arn't escaped properly. You need single quotes around each parameter, not the whole group. Try the following.

```
->extras("onclick = helper_reschedule_in_reschedule('".$row->company_id."', '".$row->ppt."', '".$row->test."', '".$row->interview."')
```

Also you need to modify your helper_reschedule_in_reschedule method to accept the extra params.

Check your reschedule_in_reschedule method also, as it looks like you've got PHP mixed with your javascript.